# How to disable Mandatory Fields in Oracle NetSuite?

Tags: java, netsuite, openair

Go to **customization > List, Records & Fields > Item fields** . Edit that custom field and on the Validation & Defaulting tab you can uncheck the mandatory field and then just save.

OR

You can navigate to **Customization >> Forms >> Entry Form**.  Then edit your form whatever it is.

I was trying to disable mandatory fields while creating an employee.

Comment: what is your question?!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no question. If you want to post a self-answered question then the question should contain a question (and no answer) and you should include an answer with the answer.